# balance stock in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having 2 tables where i am supposed to show in qty, out qty and balance qty of items in stock i wrote my query as below:

```
SELECT I.Date as Date, 
P.ResourceName as ItemName,
P.ResourceRate as Rate,
i.TotalInQty as InwardsQuantity,
s.TotalOutQty as OutwardsQuantity,
i.TotalInQty-S.TotalOutQty as Balance,
O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit
FROM UnitMaster O
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P
 ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode
LEFT JOIN
(
  select sum(i.Qty) TotalInQty, Nameofitem
  from Inwards_Master I
  group by Nameofitem
) I
ON I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName
LEFT JOIN
(
  select sum(s.qty) TotalOutQty, Nameofitem
  from Outwards_Master S 
  group by s.Nameofitem
) S
ON I.Date=S.Date 
AND I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem
WHERE P.TenderCode=1
```

the above query is giving me an error like below:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Column 'Inwards_Master.Date' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

can any 1 please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are not selecting the `Date` column  from the table reference `i` not `s`, you should include it in the select list with an aggregate function `MIN` or `MAX`, or include it in the `GROUP BY` clause like so:

```
SELECT 
  I.Date as Date, 
  P.ResourceName as ItemName,
  P.ResourceRate as Rate,
  i.TotalInQty as InwardsQuantity,
  s.TotalOutQty as OutwardsQuantity,
  i.TotalInQty - S.TotalOutQty as Balance,
  O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit
FROM UnitMaster O
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode
LEFT JOIN
(
  select 
    sum(i.Qty) TotalInQty, 
    "Date",
    Nameofitem
  from Inwards_Master I
  group by Nameofitem, "Date"
) I
ON I.Nameofitem = P.ResourceName
LEFT JOIN
(
  select 
    sum(s.qty) TotalOutQty, 
    "Date",
    Nameofitem
  from Outwards_Master S 
  group by s.Nameofitem, "Date"
) S  ON I.Date       = S.Date 
    AND I.Nameofitem = S.Nameofitem
WHERE P.TenderCode = 1;
```

**Or:** If you didn't need to `GROUP BY` date, then what date you want to get for each grouped `Nameofitem`?

You have to use an aggregate function in this case. For instance `MAX(Date)` to get the latest date like so:

```
...
LEFT JOIN
(
  select 
    sum(i.Qty) TotalInQty, 
    MAX("Date") LatestDate,
    Nameofitem
  from Inwards_Master I
  group by Nameofitem
) I
```

The same for `s`.

Comment: +1, I forgot to do it for `Outwards_Master` too in my answer - edited.

Comment: hey @mahmoud gamal i just hav 1 small prob, it is not showing balance for those items where there is no outwards, like if there was inwards on that day and no outwards then it shows null in that row, can u help me out on that?

Comment: @kunaljangade I can't understand your tables' structures, but try `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: with    RIGHT JOIN i get empty tables

Comment: @kunaljangade Can you please post the two tables structure with some sample data and the desired output? And if possible try to set up a demo in [**this site**](http://sqlfiddle.com) this will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as it says - so try including `I.Date` and `S.Date` in an aggregate:

```
SELECT I.Date as Date, 
P.ResourceName as ItemName,
P.ResourceRate as Rate,
i.TotalInQty as InwardsQuantity,
s.TotalOutQty as OutwardsQuantity,
i.TotalInQty-S.TotalOutQty as Balance,
O.UnitSymbol As ItemUnit
FROM UnitMaster O
INNER JOIN Resource_Master P
 ON O.UnitCode = P.Unitcode
LEFT JOIN
(
  select COALESCE(sum(i.Qty), 0) AS TotalInQty, Nameofitem, Min(I.Date) AS Date
  from Inwards_Master I
  group by Nameofitem
) I
ON I.Nameofitem= P.ResourceName
LEFT JOIN
(
  select COALESCE(sum(s.qty), 0) AS TotalOutQty, Nameofitem, Min(S.Date) AS Date
  from Outwards_Master S 
  group by s.Nameofitem
) S
ON I.Date=S.Date 
AND I.Nameofitem =S.Nameofitem
WHERE P.TenderCode=1
```

Comment: i got exactly what i wanted but it is showing me null as balance in those items where there is no outwards on that day, can u help me on that

Comment: @kunaljangade OK I've edited, hopefully quantities and balance should now show 0 instead of null where there is no matching inward or outward.

Comment: see i am i having an error in this and also that i want to see details of all the days means i want to have stocks for each and everyday separately date wise and balance = total inwards + new inwards when there is no outwards on that day. the error i get is as below:
    Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @kunaljangade If you're trying to change this query further but encountering an error, I'd suggest posting a new question so people can see the script you've got so far.

Comment: but this thing was working fine yesterday i just need to show the balance and its done. can u help me on that?

Comment: When I edited I didn't touch any of the date columns, and there is no conversion between dates and other formats in this query. Have you changed the query at all since you ran this? If so, can you post it somewhere (edit to the question perhaps?)